# TkInter sending String to IntVar

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is one of my Tkinter windows designed as an entry form. It has a number of rows (normally defined by another function) and a set number of columns, defined by len(self.names).

The Tkinter Int and String variables are getting created correctly but when setting the value of the Int based upon the value in the entry widget, it throws an error saying invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. I understand that you can't set a string to an int, but even before I try to set the value, it's apparent that the textvariable isn't 'linked' properly to the IntVar because whereas in other windows the entry widget has a default value of 0 where an IntVar underpins it, in this case this doesn't happen.

You should be able to run the code below, it's a (mostly) working class.

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *

class app:

    def __init__(self):

        self.getFiles()

    def getFiles(self):
        self.numHelidays = 2
        root=Tk()
        self.master=root

        self.files = []
        self.names = ("HELI", "DAY", "DATE (yyyymmdd)", "type or browse for group shapefiles", "type or browse for route shapefiles")

        i = 0
        for f in self.names:
            self.fileLabel=Label(self.master,text=f)
            self.fileLabel.grid(column=i, row=0)
            i = i+1

        for heliday in range(self.numHelidays):
            self.files.append([])
            col = 0
            for column in self.names:
                if col == 3 or col == 4:
                    self.fileEntry=Entry(self.master,width=60, textvariable = self.files[heliday].append(StringVar()))
                else:
                    self.fileEntry=Entry(self.master,width=60, textvariable = self.files[heliday].append(IntVar()))
                #self.files[heliday][col].set(self.fileEntry)
                self.fileEntry.grid(column = col, row=heliday+1)

                col = col+1

#now for 'next' button
        self.submit = Button(self.master, text="Finish...", command=self.fileManager, fg="red")
        self.submit.grid(row=(self.numHelidays)+2, column=0)

      #  self.quit = Button(self.master, text="Quit...", command=self.deleteData, fg="red")
      #  self.quit.grid(row=(self.numHelidays)+2, column=1)

    def fileManager(self):
        print self.files
        for i in self.files:
            for l in i:
                print l.get()

app()
```

EDIT:

It now works in this format. It seems that trying to append the string/intvar to the list whilst also trying to assign it to textvariable doesn't work, I had to create the string/intvar before assigning it to textvariable, then append it afterwards. I don't see why this should work but the above doesn't, because surely it's doing the same thing. I guess Python's just doing things in the wrong order in the above script.

```
            if col == 3 or col == 5:
                txt = StringVar()
                self.fileEntry=Entry(self.master,width=60, textvariable = txt)
                self.fileEntry.grid(column = col, row=heliday+1)
            else col == 2:
                txt = IntVar()
                self.fileEntry=Entry(self.master,width=20, textvariable = txt)
                self.fileEntry.grid(column = col, row=heliday+1)

            self.files[heliday].append(txt)
            self.files[heliday][col].set(txt.get())
            col = col+1
```

Comment: How does this code illustrate the problem? Where do you try to "set the value of the relevant IntVar"? When it throws an error, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, a textvariable is supposed to be a StringVar instance.  You have to convert the string you get to any other class, as with int.

Because tcl works with strings, Vars are set to strings even if you pass a non-string object to .set().  However, Intvar.get() calls int on the string, so if it cannot be converted to an int, ValueError is raised.

```
>>> root=tk.Tk()
>>> i = tk.IntVar(root)
>>> i.set(11)
>>> i.get()
11
>>> i.set('11')
>>> i.get()
11
>>> i.set(11.3)
>>> i.get()
11
>>> i.set('abc')
>>> i.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    i.get()
  File "C:\Programs\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 358, in get
    return getint(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
>>> i.set([1])
>>> i.get()
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1]'
```

When you have questions, experiment like this to determine how things actually work.